# It's possible to host php website with opencv?

Tags: php, html, opencv

I want to create a website that need OpenCV . and i want to know if its possible to host website in the web with OpenCV functions that i need in my website  ??

if yes can you give me a simple tutorial ? because opencv need to be installed on Linux or windows but how to set up opencv on the host server ???

Comment: Yes it is, good luck with it!

Comment: do you know how to set up opencv on the host server ?

Comment: given, how good the python wrappers are, it's outright stupid to want php instead

Comment: why you delete my comment and not the comment of berak that says "Stupid" .. you dont like logical comments ..... who learn two letters in his life is voting here by negative and insulting peopling just to feel superieur to them ... before learning programing go and learn how act .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking are there any web hosts that will let you run OpenCV code, then yes. Most VPS hosts will let you install whatever software on the server you need, all you do is SSH into it, and if it's a Deb, platform per-say you may install anything you want with 'apt-get... '

For example, rackspace (http://www.rackspace.com/) is a vps host like what I've mentioned.